# Mahapps.Metro dark background not showing in designer - everything is invisible

Tags: wpf, themes, mahapps.metro

I've had this problem previously and never managed to solve it. I just created a new project, added Mahhapps Metro and set the dark theme to my window, as the quick start guide states. Not done much else.

The designer, at first, loaded no themes. So it showed as mostly default and ran using the dark theme - I could work with that.

However, after running for a bit the designer applied half the theme (Seems to be after visual studio restart). Or at least, all the components are themed, but the dark background was not applied. The result is... invisible components, being white-on-white:

[image]

Does anyone know a work around for this? Any way to force the designer to stick to a theme?

Edit: Should have included this by defaut, sorry. Here's the App.xml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrontendUI"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and main window xaml:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrontendUI"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="FrontendUI.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,44,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="120,44,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

I've found a kind-of workaround by changing the default background colour of the designer (so the components in, say, user controls can be visible with their standard transparent backgrounds) and just putting a background colour on the window, so any components on there can be seen.

Comment: For `Mahapps` 1.1.3 it doesn't apply either themes at design time, only at run time. Show your `App.xaml` and `MainWindow.xaml`.

Comment: Done! Should have put that in. Also, checked version I'm using: 1.2.4.0

Comment: You're setting your `Grid` background.... take it out just to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, Sorry, this code was copied after my attempts to workaround by setting a dark background (it lets me see the components at least). The screenshot and described behavior are with no grid background.

Comment: What `Mahapps` version are you using? The problem you're describing does not happen to me. I'm using version 1.1.3.

Comment: 1.2.4.0. I'll see if I can downgrade to test